# Magento 2: Want to add versioning in style.css

Tags: magento2, css, versioning

I want to add style.css?v=1.1 but when i add these version it call at the end of all other css files which distort website design. so what should i do?[image]

Comment: why you need versioning.Can you please explain ? Magento already add versioning on at static folder.

Comment: yes but the problem with that versioning is - for every style change i must delete the style.css file from pub/static.. folder before running static:deploy command this is why i want to use this type of versioning